# Reading text file line by line and put into separate strings: line1, line2, line3, etc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to read a file line by line and put the lines into separate strings: line1, line2, line3, etc. (max total lines will be 13 always, size of the text lines can vary between 3-99 characters).

The purpose is to send to send the lines into an SQL command to fill a database. The last part I've got working, but I can't seem to decently get some remaining data from a text file and put the separate lines into seperate strings. I keep getting segmentation faults.

Can anyone help me with an example please?

Comment: Show the code which generates the seg-faults.

Answer (score 1):

Just gessing because you did not show relevant code.

Segmentation faults when reading a text file are generally caused by unallocated memory, that is char pointers pointing nowhere

Here is an example reading 13 lines of maximum size 99, with a 2D char array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 13
#define  SIZE 101

int main() {
    int i;
    char lines[ROWS][SIZE];
    char *cr;

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
        cr = fgets(lines[i], SIZE, stdin);
        if (cr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Only %d lines found\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if ((*cr != 0) && (cr[strlen(cr) - 1] != '\n')) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Line %d is too long\n", i + 1);
            char buf[256];
            do {
                cr = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
                if (cr == NULL || *cr == '\0') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fata error line %d\n", i+1);
                    return 1;
                }
            } while (cr[strlen(cr) - 1] != '\n');
        }
    }
    /* do what you want with the 2D array lines
    ... */
    return 0;
}
```

But this `char *line[13]` would have cause undefined behaviour (and likely SIGSEGV) because the memory would have not been allocated.